# Is there a language (or language spec) to extract elements from a DAG

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs, graph-traversal, language-specifications

I have a problem where I have a huge number of DAGs and I have to visit each DAG, and extract many different sets of items.

This may sound a bit abstract so let me use an example. Xpath or JSONPath are languages that specify how i can extract an element from an xml document or a json document. They are an efficient way to represent a specific element from such a document. So if I had a huge number of xml documents and I wanted to allow consumers to specify what they want from each document, I would have them provide me with an xpath expression and I would use that to provide each of them the element they are looking for from every document.

In this case I have many DAGs and my consumers each want to extract several items from each DAG (not just one item). I'm trying to design a specification whereby people can represent what they want from each such DAG (with the ability to specify specific elements, with predicates of different complexity). I'm wondering if there already is a language spec that makes sense for the purpose I'm describing.

If this does not exist for DAGs, but exists for Trees, that too would be very useful.

Comment: Is there a reasonable graph root? XPath works by describing the path from root to a node. In a DAG, there might be multiple paths, but each path still ends at one unique node. Hence, XPath or any other language that describes paths can be used to describe paths in a DAG too.

Comment: there is a reasonable root. I was thinking of using xpath. One problem is that the ancestor axis will now behave differently, but the other is that xpath serves to find one item. I could use a list of xpaths, but I was wondering if there is already a better specification for exactly this problem.

Comment: A path still specifies a single node in a DAG; it's just that there's possibly more than one path in a DAG whereas a path in a tree is unique.